# How to switch a remote repository to a different branch

Tags: git, git-remote

I have three local and three remote branches and want to be on the same branch on both.

**On local:**

```
git branch
  A
* B
  master

git branch -r
  origin/A
  origin/B
  origin/master
```

**On remote:**

```
git branch
  A
  B
* master
```

I am able to commit, push and pull B, but my update hook deploys master instead of B. I suppose because the remote branch is still set to *master*. I created branch B using:

```
git branch B
git checkout B
git push origin B
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to change a remote's current branch with `git push`. Pushing will just copy your local changes up into that repository. Typically remotes you push to should be `--bare`, without a working directory (and thus no "current branch").

Comment: I think you're right and this wasn't my issue anyway. The issue is that I'm using the update hook and so the git archive inside it doesn't get the last commit, or something. All i know is my deployed branch is one commit behind the local push

Comment: Could you post relevant parts of your hook script?

Comment: This is my update hook `git archive $1 | tar -x -C /local/B/ rsync -arq \ --exclude ".git" \ --delete --delete-excluded \ /local/B/ me@dev:/remotedev/html/B/`

Comment: That looks right... When you `git push origin B` it should call `git archive B`. Try adding `echo "$1"` to the hook to verify the argument value.

Comment: Yes `echo $1` gives `ref/heads/B`, when I push B which is "the name of the ref being updated" [per githook docs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html).  I figured out if I use the post-update hook instead it works as expected.  The docs for post-update say it "takes a variable number of parameters, each of which is the name of ref that was actually updated".  Will $1 always be the same in update as post-update hook? Maybe that's a better question.

Answer (score 64):

Below is my method to switch and work for a remote branch of a Git repository.

Have a look for all the branches first, just input following command in the terminal:

```
git branch --all
```

And then you will see the all the branches on local and remote. Something like this:

```
*master
remotes/origin/develop
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/web
remotes/origin/app
```

Let's pretend you want to switch to the `remotes/origin/develop` branch. Type following:

```
git checkout remotes/origin/develop
```

Then type `git branch --all` again to find this:

```
*(detached from remotes/origin/develop)
master
remotes/origin/develop
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/web
remotes/origin/app
```

And then just do:

```
git checkout -b develop
```

From now on, you are working on the `remotes/origin/develop` branch exactly.

Comment: I think the answer was slightly different. OP was asking how to switch the current branch of a remote repo..

Comment: Can you add what ```git checkout -b <branch>``` does or point to the documentation that spells it out?

Answer (score 8):

```
To switch to a remote repo
git branch -r ## list all the branches including the remote branches
git switch <branchname>
```