# How can I automatically get git to push a local branch to a different remote branch

Tags: git

I have a deploy branch which differs from my master in that it contains various server-only asset files that I don't want polluting my master in development but I would like pushed to master on my server. Currently I type in the following git command every time I want to push my code:

```
git push heroku deploy:master
```

How do I modify my .git/config file so that I could achieve the same with

```
git push heroku
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to switch to a different remote branch in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736987/how-to-switch-to-a-different-remote-branch-in-git)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pushing from local master to a remote non-master branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744947/pushing-from-local-master-to-a-remote-non-master-branch)

Answer (score 3):

You have to make `deploy` track `heroku/master`. This could be achieved with

```
git branch --set-upstream deploy heroku/master
```

See the documentation of [`git branch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html) for more details on that.

Another alternative: after your first `git push heroku deploy:master`, you could throw away your `deploy` branch (`git checkout master && git branch -D deploy`) and then create `deploy` from `heroku/master` again:

```
git checkout -b deploy heroku/master
```

This will set up tracking automatically.

The topic of tracking is also discussed in the [Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#Tracking-Branches) and on [git ready](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/03/09/remote-tracking-branches.html).

Comment: I tried your first suggestion and it didn't work. I think this may be due to my existing .git/config heroku entry. The totality of my config is: [remote "heroku"]
  url = git@heroku.com:myapp.git
[branch "deploy"]
 remote = .
 merge = refs/remotes/heroku/master

Comment: More specifically: "git push" tells me everything is up to date. "git push heroku" is better and it pushes the deploy branch but also attempts to push my master branch and fails for not fast forward updates given that my master differs from the heroku master, since I don't keep cached assets there. I think this may be due to my existing .git/config heroku entry, as given above.

Comment: the `branch` stuff seems correct but in my `config` files, there's always the line `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` on the `[remote]` entries.

Answer (score 1):

Set your config so that you don't have to worry about it

```
git config --global push.default tracking
```

Now each time you push, it will set up the tracking for subsequent pushes.